# Variant array of String contains alternate spaces

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll

I created a C++ DLL, when called from VBA returns SAFEARRAY*.

My VBA Function :

```
Declare Function GetData_V Lib "xyz.dll" (ByVal path As String, ByVal id As String, ByRef inputArr() As String, ByRef output() As String) As Variant()
```

My C++ implementation :

```
SafeArrayLock(*outputArray); 
    for (LONG i = 0; i < countElements; i++)
    {
        CComBSTR bstr = CComBSTR(outputCustom[i]);
        SafeArrayPutElement(*outputArray, &i, bstr);
    }
    SafeArrayUnlock(*outputArray); 

    delete [] outputCustom;

    return *outputArray;
```

Where outputCustom is defined as

```
outputCustom = new char*[nCount+1];
```

In VBA when I check the output it shows string as :

```
1 0 . 9 4 4 9 d 0 
2 . 8 3 4 6 d 0 
0 . 0 1 1 8 d 0 
0 . 6 2 9 9 d 0 
0 . 6 2 9 9 d 0 
0 . 6 2 9 9 d 0 
2 5 . 0 d 0 
0 . 0 7 6 4 d 0 
1 0 . 9 4 4 9 d 0 
2 . 8 3 4 6 d 0 
0 . 0 1 1 8 d 0
```

I debugged the code and checked the values of *outputArray in C++ but everything is fine there, but when I checked my array in VBA it got extra spaces in between each character of each strings.

Comment: Here's a blog I found of someone doing the same - The conclusion is as per the answer of `A A` https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/271964/returning-array-of-string-from-c-dll-to-vba

Answer (score 2):

VBA, like VB6, expects Unicode (wide-character) strings.

[How to: Access DLLs in Excel -- Variant and String Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Excel works internally with wide-character Unicode strings. When a VBA user-defined function is declared as taking a String argument, Excel converts the supplied string to a byte-string in a locale-specific way. If you want your function to be passed a Unicode string, your VBA user-defined function should accept a Variant instead of a String argument. Your DLL function can then accept that Variant BSTR wide-character string from VBA.

The spaces you see are the zero byte high bytes of the 16 bit chars. You need to use `wchar_t` and/or convert to widechar before passing the strings to `CComBSTR`s constructor. You can use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx), [`mbstowcs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) to do it.

A good tip to see what VBA expect is to pass such object from VB to your DLL and inspect it there.

[Eric’s Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/) is also an interesting read.